# Export - Internal render vs Cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, export

I saw this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tovu1A0LxeQ

And now I'm trying to export my model into obj file with textures. However, seems this is not possible to achieve with the cycles render (from what I read).

So, is there a way to do the same process using the internal render, so that I can have my obj/mtl file referencing the uv layout png file?

The final goal is to publish my model into Facebook, which needs glb file. So I was trying to get first the correct obj file and then convert it to the glb file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Blender 2.8 (currently in beta) can export directly to glTF (`.glb`, `.gltf`), including the key properties of Principled BSDF materials (base color, metalness, roughness).